# PHP ~ Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to insert into two tables but get this error

> Error: INSERT INTO provide_help (amount) VALUES ( 40,000.00) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

below is my insert code

```
<?php

    session_start(); {



    //Include database connection details
    include('../../dbconnect.php');


$amount =  strip_tags($_POST['cat']);
$field1amount = $_POST['cat'];
$field2amount = $field1amount + ($field1amount*0.5);



$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount) VALUES ( $field1amount)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 


$sql = "INSERT INTO gh (ph_id, amount) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $field2amount)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 

 {
    $_SESSION['ph'] ="<center><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Request Accepted.</div></center>";
   header("location: PH.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

but when i do some thing like this it works

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount) VALUES ( $field2amount)";
```

i just change the `$field1amount` to `$field2amount`

but i dont want it that way i want to also get the value of `$field1amount` and insert it

please any help will be appriciated, thanks

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! That would also solve your comma problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is because the number you're passing in has a comma in it and isn't a string. You need to either pass in `"40,000.00"` or `40000.00`. MySQL is interpreting it as two values: `40` and `000.00`.

Using prepared statements will alleviate this (and your security issue) because binding will interpret `40,000.00` as a string.  A very basic example to get you started would be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

/*
    - the "s" below means string
    - NOTE you should still validate the $_POST value,
      don't just accept whatever is sent through your form - 
      make sure it matches the format you're expecting at least
      or you'll have data validation issues later on
*/
$stmt->bindParam("s", $field1amount);
$stmt->execute($fieldAmount1);
$result = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: My recommendation would actually be to use PDO if at all possible.  See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php to connect to a database and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php to prepare statements, bind parameters, and execute the query.